# Issue with Sending Large(<1 MB) payload in POST request in Browser

Tags: reactjs, http, post, redux, base64

Backend Architecture:
The backend system is designed to format requests as XML data and then encrypt them using the AES-GCM algorithm before sending to the server. The file is sent as a buffer text within the XML body.

```xml
<Request>
    <Session>140422815169328</Session>
    <Function>cloud::writeFile</Function>
    <ArgList>
        <Argument name="user">user</Argument>
        <Argument name="fileHandle">secret-handle</Argument>
        <Argument name="buffer">base 64 encoded text</Argument> // <-- file data
    </ArgList>
</Request>
```

**Issue Description:**
When attempting to call the API with a slightly smaller file (around 500 KB), the upload is successful, and the file can be read. However, when attempting to upload a slightly larger file (about 1.3 MB), the request is not sent to the server. No request is visible in the network section, indicating that the transmission process is not initiated.

```js
export const uploadFile = createAsyncThunk(
  'uploadService/uploadFile',
  async ({ sessionId, user, fileHandle, fileBuffer }) => {
    console.log('before uploading') // this line logged to the console, and rest of the code is not running
    const response = await UploadingService.writeFile({
      sessionId,
      user,
      fileHandle,
      buffer: fileBuffer,
    })

    console.log('after uploading') // nothing in console
    console.log(response) // nope --
    await UploadingService.closeFile({ sessionId, user, fileHandle })
  }
)
```

[image]

[image]

as you can see this, only the first request is being made, not write file request

**Request for Assistance:**
I am seeking guidance on identifying and resolving the issue with uploading larger files. The current implementation seems to work for smaller files, but there is a roadblock when dealing with files around 1.3 MB. Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting and resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.